# Which action in case of copy/paste

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

Today, I found this question: *[How to delete a column from a table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968494/how-to-delete-a-column-from-a-table-in-mysql)*

The first answer displayed, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54670536/3128122, makes me unconfortable. It's a copy/paste of another answer on the same question (from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392780/3128122).

Should I do anything (flag, -1, or another) about this copy/paste?

I read this question about copy/paste over different questions: [Is it okay to copy-paste answers from other questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78658/is-it-okay-to-copy-paste-answers-from-other-questions)

But, I don't know if I can do anything.

Thanks. It's my first meta question :)

Comment: Why do you think the answer is a copy-paste? The answer is so short and the variable names so common, I guess this could just be a duplicate without copy-pasing.

Comment: Use a custom moderator flag, and explain the situation.

Comment: Don't flag as NAA. ___It is an answer___. It may not be good, it may be a copy, but it ___is___ an answer. Cases like this can be downvoted or custom-flagged. NAA flags will get declined on this.

Comment: To be fair, most of the answers on that page are more-or-less identical, just with different variations of `columnName`, `<colname>`, `your_col`, etc.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker That's right and several other answers in that style (which don't   add any more information than the "top" answers) were already deleted (you need 10k reputation to see them). That answer, and certainly some others, could be cleaned up as well. It worries me a bit more that 6 persons thought that answer (and the others in that style) are helpful. Some people are handing out upvotes like candy.

Comment: But, this type of answer don't require any action ? I agree, it could be a duplicate without copy/paste.

Comment: Samuel, the Q&A has been protected since 2016 to prevent more answers in the same vein from being posted. So in this case, the moderators were informed about the problem and took care of the worst "offenses" already. (You can't see those, yet, but once you reach 10k reputation you can.) So, *in this case*, no action is required. It's good that you're aware and watching for problems :-) As Cerbrus mentioned, when you come across *new* content of this nature, a custom moderator flag could be appropriate...

Comment: ...I've also had some success with "low quality* flagging along with a *comment* below the post, saying the question has already been answered with the same (or better) information and what the OP feels their answer contributes. That makes it clearer for reviewers/mods what the flag is for.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers. I just looking for improve stackoverflow good answers readability. I'll try to flag it with low quality (I already put a comment). Thank you again, Stackoverflow (and it's community) is awesome !